CLI tool to find the best match of a reference image in a directory
I am looking for a Linux CLI software which can print a "similarity score" of a given reference picture compared to all pictures within a folder.
The reference picture is a resized, low-resolution version of one the picture present in the folder.
The reference picture may not be exactly the same as the original. It may be very slightly cropped or modified.
The goal is to find the picture which has the best match, which will be the original one.
findimagedupes is a good candidate but AFAIK it can only find all the pictures which have a similarity score better than a threshold. What I want to do is to sort all the pictures of my collection according to their similarity score.

You could quite simply roll your own with Python + SciKit.Image starting from the example given here for Structural Similarity. You might find this article also useful.
